# Equivalent functions in ArcMap compared to MapInfo: Objects > Combine

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mapinfo

What is the equivalent of MapInfo's Objects > Combine in ArcMap? I have a polyline layer which is divided into 10m subsections, I want to combines these and find parts which are >50m combined. I have done this before using MapInfo by combining the disaggregating the lines (multipart to singlepart), but ideally I'd like to be able to do this in Arc, rather than ping-ponging a file between .shp and .tab format.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know MapInfo, so I don't actually know if it's the same, but I would suggest you take a look at the Dissolve Tool (ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Generalization > Dissolve).  This will work at least if your features to have something to join them based on.  For example, a road network where you want to join split up road segments into single feature for each road.  Otherwise, if you want to join all the line layers that touch, regardless of geometry, then you could add a field to the attribute table, calculate it's value as 1, or whatever you want so long as all the features have the same value, and then run the same Dissolve tool on it using that new field as the dissolve field.  In that case you would just want to carefully manage the Create Multipart and Unsplit Lines options to get the desired outcome.  And if you output the results of the tool to a feature class in a geodatabase instead of to a shapefile, it will actually even auto-calculate lengths of each resulting segment for you as a ShapeLength field (unit of measure will be determined by unit of measure for the feature class's coordinate system).

Again, I don't know MapInfo so this may or may not get you where you're really wanting to go, but, hope it helps.